# Find the phase difference of a sine wave in verilog . Sine wave is represented in 16 bit binary in 60 address location of the ram . Brief alogarithm

Tags: memory, verilog, adc

frequency of the sine wave is 1 khz .

Max Amplitude of the sine wave is 4.97 V in IEEE 754 floating point format

Similarly other values values of the wave which is converted in to 16 bit binary .

Want some ideas to create an alogarithm at first to use this values to find phase difference of the sine wave .

The LUT created till know to read the values :

```
Memory Created :

module ram_memory_2(clk,add,data);

    input [5:0]add;
    input clk;
    output reg [15:0]data;
   

    always @ (*)
    begin
       case(add)
            0  : data <= 16'b0011011010010011;
            1  : data <= 16'b0011011011111010;
            2  : data <= 16'b0011011011111010;
            3  : data <= 16'b0011011101110001;
            4  : data <= 16'b0011011110101010;
            5  : data <= 16'b0011011111010111;
            6  : data <= 16'b0011011111100111;
            7  : data <= 16'b0011011111110100;
            8  : data <= 16'b0011011111011111;
            9  : data <= 16'b0011011111001111;
            10 : data <= 16'b0011011110011110;
            11 : data <= 16'b0011011101101101;
            12 : data <= 16'b0011011100110011;
            13 : data <= 16'b0011011011100001;
            14 : data <= 16'b0011011001111111;
            15 : data <= 16'b0011011000100001;
            16 : data <= 16'b0011010110100010;
            17 : data <= 16'b0011010100100011;
            18 : data <= 16'b0011010010011100;
            19 : data <= 16'b0011010000001100;
            20 : data <= 16'b0011001011100001;
            21 : data <= 16'b0011000110100010;
            22 : data <= 16'b0011000001010010;
            23 : data <= 16'b0010111000101011;
            24 : data <= 16'b0010101010101110;
            25 : data <= 16'b0010000110100010;
            26 : data <= 16'b1010100000001011;
            27 : data <= 16'b1010110010011000;
            28 : data <= 16'b1010111100111011;
            29 : data <= 16'b1011000011101110;
            30 : data <= 16'b1011001000111101;
            31 : data <= 16'b1011001101011100;
            32 : data <= 16'b1011010001001010;
            33 : data <= 16'b1011010011011101;
            34 : data <= 16'b1011010101100000;
            35 : data <= 16'b1011010111010011;
            36 : data <= 16'b1011011001000010;
            37 : data <= 16'b1011011010101000;
            38 : data <= 16'b1011011011111010;
            39 : data <= 16'b1011011101001100;
            40 : data <= 16'b1011011110001101;
            41 : data <= 16'b1011011110111010;
            42 : data <= 16'b1011011111010011;
            43 : data <= 16'b1011011111011011;
            44 : data <= 16'b1011011111101100;
            45 : data <= 16'b1011011111100011;
            46 : data <= 16'b1011011111000011;
            47 : data <= 16'b1011011110011110;
            48 : data <= 16'b1011011101011100;
            49 : data <= 16'b1011011100100011;
            50 : data <= 16'b1011011011001001;
            51 : data <= 16'b1011011001101010;
            52 : data <= 16'b1011011000000100;
            53 : data <= 16'b1011010110001101;
            54 : data <= 16'b1011010100001010;
            55 : data <= 16'b1011010001111011;
            56 : data <= 16'b1011001111010111;
            57 : data <= 16'b1011001010011000;
            58 : data <= 16'b1011000101011000;
            59 : data <= 16'b1011000000011001;
            default: data <= 16'b0000000000000000; // default case if address not listed
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search this table to find positions and subtraction of two addresses give you phase difference.
Next time you can use some linear approximation for more precise results.